# I am having trouble with serialization, i need to implement it in java

Tags: java, serialization

I have created a program, it is a guessing game but i am having problems learning this new method to serialize it. I have everything already done i just need to make it so the program can save and load open through the method of serialization. I am trying to serialize the "game" part or the play() method of the program so when the next time it loads it willl load the old information.

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;

 //Node class
 class Node
{
//instance variables
public String questionText;
public Node leftChild;
public Node rightChild;

public void displayText()
{
    System.out.println(questionText);
}
 }


  //Tree class
 class Tree implements Serializable
 {
private Node root;

//constructor
public Tree()
{   root = new Node();
    root.leftChild = new Node();
    root.rightChild = new Node();
    root.questionText = "Does it live on land?";
    root.leftChild.questionText ="bear";  // left side is Yes, right side is No
    root.rightChild.questionText = "parrot";
}

public void instruction()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Think of an animal, I will try to guess it, answer yes or no");
}


public void play()
{
 Node current = root;
 Node parent = current;
 boolean isLeftChild = true;


 while(true)
 {   parent = current;
     int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,current.questionText );
     //code here for yes
     if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
     {
        current = current.leftChild;
        isLeftChild=true;
     }
     //code here for no
     else if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
     {
        current = current.rightChild;
        isLeftChild = false;
     }


     if (current.leftChild == null && current.rightChild == null)
     {
         int secondQ = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Is your animal a " + current.questionText + "?");

         if (secondQ == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
         {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I Guessed your animal!");
           return;
         }
         else if (secondQ == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
         {
             Node nodeOne = new Node();
             Node nodeTwo = new Node();

              nodeOne.questionText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a question that differentiates your animal from the animal I guessed, it would be yes for your animal");

              nodeTwo.questionText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is this animal?");

              nodeOne.rightChild = current;
              nodeOne.leftChild = nodeTwo;

              // parent.leftChild = nodeOne or parent.rightChild = nodeOne
              if(isLeftChild == false)
              {
                  parent.rightChild = nodeOne;
                  System.out.println("right child");
              }
              else
                  {
                  parent.leftChild = nodeOne;
                  System.out.println("left Child");
                  }
              return;




         }


     }

}
}


public void preOrder(Node localRoot)
{
if(localRoot != null)
   {
   System.out.print(localRoot.questionText + " ");
   preOrder(localRoot.leftChild);
   preOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
   }
}

public Node getRoot(){
    return root;
}
}




public class GuessTheAnimal 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Tree animal = new Tree();
  animal.instruction();
  animal.play();
  animal.play();



 }

}
```

Comment: I do not know how to implement it, and needed help doing so.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [Java serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm):

```
FileOutputStream fileOut =
new FileOutputStream("node.ser");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
out.writeObject(tree);
out.close();
```

Reading is similarly easy:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("employee.ser");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
tree = (Tree) in.readObject();
in.close();
```

Comment: +1 no need for `fileIn.close();` and `fileOut.close();`, since `in.close();` and `out.close();` will close them for you. :)

Comment: IS there any location that i would put this at? Within the Tree class, before and after?

Comment: In the main method, IMO. That's hard to tell though without more solid requirements of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You wouldn't do it in your Tree class.  However, that does show another problem with your design - you should look separating your program logic from your data tree.  Your GuessTheAnimal class should have all the logic on how to Serialize / Deserialize the Tree, how to traverse the tree, and ask the questions, and your Tree class should simply contain Nodes of question / animal pairs.  That would in itself probably help clear up some questions about Serialization, what actually gets serialized, and where it should happen.

Comment: I am just trying to save the information gathered from the user in the "play()" Method so that the next time the program is run, all the old answers are still present

Comment: Right, but all that Play is doing, is adding Nodes to the Tree.  What you are serializing is not "Play()", it is the Tree, and the Tree's nodes.  Hence, it might make more sense if you moved Play() into GuessTheAnimal, and left the Tree class as simply a data structure.  What Serialization IS, after all, is a way to save your Data Structures for future use.

Comment: OH okay, so in this example, that he has written when i implement it the lowercase 'tree' does not exist, is that supposed to be an object? should i make a Tree tree = new Tree(); or would that mess everything up?

Comment: If you have no serialized file to read, then Tree tree = new Tree();  If a file does exist, then Tree tree = in.readObject();

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with the code.

First, your Tree implements Serializable, but that is not sufficient.  You need to tell the program (probably early on after the program start), to Read your serialized file, and initialize your Tree from that input stream.  Conversely, when you are ready to save your state (probably right before program exit), you need to write your Tree out to your serialized file.

Secondly, your Tree implements Serializable, but your tree is built of Node objects, which do not implement Serializable.  All members of your serializable class must be themselves serializable for Serialization to work.

A good tutorial on [Java Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Comment: Yeah i didn't really know where to start with it, i will look over the guide, i have read some others but do not fully understand them, which is why i posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad.
An answer that should get you on your way is that first, you should make your Tree class implement java.io.Serializable:

class Tree implements Serializable {
...
}

Then, make sure all the fields Tree implement Serializable in the same way (and so on for their fields)

When this is done you can use an ObjectOutputStream to write the Tree instance out and  an ObjectInputStream to read it.

E.g.  new ObjectOutputStream(new FileInputStream("filename")).writeObject(tree)

But you need to read about Serializable and ObjectOutputSteam a little first, I would suggest.